# how to capture the canvas drawn signature without background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, canvas, signature

Right now I am saving the drawn signature on the canvas as a image, but as soon as I display the image in my UIImageView, a white background is also displaying. I don't want to display it with a white background, I just wanted to display the signature. How can I achieve that?

Here is the piece of code for saving:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; 


CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;  
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(10, 50, 640, 300);

/* Get the entire on screen map as Image */
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * Image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   


/* Crop the desired region */
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(Image1.CGImage, cropRect);
UIImage * cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
CGImageRelease(imageRef);   

UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 

canvasImage.image = cropImage;

//for saving image to documents directory
NSArray *paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory1 = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath1 = [documentsDirectory1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder/signatureImage.png"];
UIImage *image = canvasImage.image; // imageView is my image from camera
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cropImage);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath1 atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Post your tries, let us know the way you did. We then will know wether you have a small bug in code, or a huge mistake by taking the wrong approach.

Comment: @TeodorCarstea please check my updated question with a piece of code.

Comment: Question: you are drawing a signature (some graphics, whatever), and you need it to be on a transparent background? Did I get you right?

Comment: @TeodorCarstea Yes. When i display in UIImageView it should be transparent, only signature should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider You have an UIImageView on which you draw.
2. Open your desired image editor, and make an image: it must be completely white and 99% transparent.

Why: you will give this image to your UIImageView, if it would be 100% transparent, the graphic context will have troubles to work with it.

So you make a white image, let's say 99.9% transparent, so the user's eyes will see a transparent image, but Objective C will see a "normal" one.

Now, this is the way I draw the signature:

Declare ivars:

```
UIImageView image_signature;
CGPoint lastP;
```

Then:

```
//___________________________________________________
-(void)drawLineFromX:(float)x fromY:(float)y toX:(float)xx toY:(float)yy{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image_signature.image.size);
    [image_signature.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, image_signature.image.size.width, image_signature.image.size.height)]; 
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), x, y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), xx, yy);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    [image_signature setImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
//___________________________________________________
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastP = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [button_authorize setEnabled:YES];

}
//___________________________________________________
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint nextP = [touch locationInView:image_signature];
    [self drawLineFromX:lastP.x fromY:lastP.y toX:nextP.x toY:nextP.y];
    lastP = nextP;
}
//___________________________________________________
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint nextP = [touch locationInView:image_signature];
    //and this will allow you to draw a point, you know, some people
    //use dots in their signatures        
    [self drawLineFromX:lastP.x fromY:lastP.y toX:nextP.x toY:nextP.y];
    lastP = nextP;
}
```

And to clear the signature (all you have drew), just load again that 99% white transparent image into "image_signature" imageView

Comment: @Teosor Carstea This is for drawing on the canvas. I need after drawing i need to capture the drawn signature.

Comment: dude, didn't you understand? you do not need to CAPTURE ANYTHING. all you have is to use "image_signature", because my method writes the signature (all you draw) instantly into it.

Comment: that's right. But my requirement is for example if i draw "S" and i need to save that drawn image as "S" without white background. What you have done is just drawing on the screen.

Comment: Dude, you didn't understand again: the imageView "image_signature" you must give a 99% transparent white image (made by yourself in GIMP or whatever). And you draw all your "S"-es on it, and at anytime you can use (don't grab anything, just use) the image of image_signature imageView. ...facepalm...